# Decentralised identity management

Tags: authentication, authorization, blockchain, hyperledger, identity

I was exploring on how to implement decentralised digital identity management system, like mobile digital ID valet for authentication and authorisation. Many solutions on the internet are based on blockchain. Can somebody explain what is the big advantage of using blockchain in this use case, why can’t this be solved by using just public key / private key cryptography?

Answer (score 1):

DIDs (Decentralized Identifiers) are globally unique and resolvable (via a ledger) without requiring any centralized resolution authority and once a decentralized identity is legally established, it can be verified by enrolled service providers within the ecosystem

`W3C` has given the following standards for `Decentralized Identity`:-

- [W3C decentralized identifiers (DIDs)](https://w3c.github.io/did-core/)
- [W3C DID resolution](https://w3c-ccg.github.io/did-resolution/)
- [W3C verifiable credentials](https://w3c.github.io/vc-data-model/)

You can look at the project called `Hyperledger Aries` [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/aries-framework-go) written in golang and provides implementations for the above `Decentralized Identity standards` given by `W3C` and also provides DID-to-DID communications, verifiable credential exchange, transaction authorizations, and data communication protocols

Self-Sovereign Identities is the concept that people and businesses can store their own identity data on their own devices, and provide it efficiently to those who need to validate it, without relying on a central repository of identity data.

> Hyperledger Indy provides tools, libraries, and reusable components
>   for providing digital identities rooted on blockchains or other
>   distributed ledgers so that they are interoperable across
>   administrative domains, applications, and any other silo. Indy is
>   interoperable with other blockchains or can be used standalone
>   powering the decentralization of identity.

[Here](https://hyperledger-indy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the official documentation to understand more into hyperledger indy and Decentralized identities

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain is a shared, replicated, permissioned ledger for recording transactions with consensus, provenance, immutability and finality.

Public-key cryptography is one of the key components of blockchain technology, so it can't be solved without it. The benefit of blockchain in the context of sharing data (where DID is a subset of) is, it solves the problem of establishing trust between 3rd parties. The involved parties or basically everyone if it's a public ledger, can verify the integrity of the shared data and that it hasn't been tampered with.

With PKC, you can verify the integrity of the shared data, but you can not be ensured that the same data is shared with every party.

Comment: For implementing decentralised IAM, I can just register the public key with a centralised agency / third party and exchange claims using PKC, here public key uniquely identifies the user and PKC ensures the data integrity. One advantage blockchain brings is to establish the trust b/w third parties, and user may not have to register with every third party. Right? . Otherwise it’s an overhead isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

As a practical implementation of decentralized authorization, you can use the [emerSSL](https://emercoin.com/en/emerssl). This system already running in production, see the [article with video](https://emercoin.com/en/news/logging-on-to-livecoinnet-with-emerssl), how it works.
For technical details, see the [whitepaper](https://emerssl.emercoin.com/EMCSSL.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you understand why you need blockchain for Decentralised identity, not just a bunch of pub/private keys.

You got a driving license and now you went to rent a car. Car rental company asked for a Driving License (DL), you either produce a physical copy or digital driving license encrypted by pub/private keys. Now car rental company has two tasked, if you produce a physical copy, they have to go to the Driving license Authority (Issuer) site and verify your driving license which is a time-consuming and costly process. Even if it is a digitally signed driving license, still they have to use Issuer services to verify your DL. Now if the issuer verification services are down/hacked/tampered, There is no way to verify the DL.

But if the same identity (DL) is issued using Blockchain Network e.g Hyperledger Indy, the Issuer ( Driving License Authority) will issue a verifiable credential (DL) to a user(citizen) and stored a signing key/pub key in a DID which is stored in a decentralized ledger which can’t be tampered and act as a single source of truth.

One important thing to note that, Verifiable credentials are stored in the user's mobile wallet, not in Blockchain.

So when the user presents a DL from his mobile wallet, Car rental company fetches the verification public key from the decentralized ledger and verify the records without ever contacting Driving License Issuing Authority.

Blockchain provides two key significant benefits:

The issuer will be eliminated from verifying process, thus saving time, cost, and bureaucracy while maintaining the same level of trust and transparency.

Identities will be citizen-centric, not Issuer-centric.

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/building-decentralize-identity-using-hyperledger-indy-aries-and-ursa-2a5d3e82fa20) if interested in Hyperledger based Decentralise identity.